# Display of last Schema.org breadcrumb entry in Google Search?

Tags: html, google-search, schema.org, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to markup my breadcrumbs according to Schema.org in order to get breadcrumbs in the Google results like this:

> Home > Category > Current page

But with my current markup it only shows:

> Home > Category

Is something missing in my markup ([example page](http://www.xn--omdmen-yxa.se/foretag/consector/))? I'm using Navxt plugin for WordPress.

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">
    <!-- Breadcrumb NavXT 5.4.0 -->
<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to Omdömen.se." href="http://www.xn--omdmen-yxa.se" class="home"><span property="name">Hem</span></a><meta property="position" content="1"></span> &raquo; <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to Företag." href="http://www.xn--omdmen-yxa.se/foretag/" class="post post-page"><span property="name">Företag</span></a><meta property="position" content="2"></span> &raquo; <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to Consector." href="http://www.xn--omdmen-yxa.se/foretag/consector/" class="post post-page current-item"><span property="name">Consector</span></a><meta property="position" content="3"></span></div>
```

You can google this to see my breadcrumb in Google Search: `site:omdömen.se inurl:consector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google’s documentation says [about breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs#about_breadcrumbs):

> The breadcrumb trail may include or omit a breadcrumb for the page on which it appears.

The documentation doesn’t contain a screenshot of their search result feature, but my guess is that Google Search displays it the same way in both cases: without an entry for the current page.

It wouldn’t make much sense to show the link for the current page in the search result snippet’s breadcrumb trail, because the primary link (i.e., the search result itself), well, already links to it.

Comment: "It wouldn’t make much sense to show the link for the current page" except the breadcrumbs are not rendered as links but as texts, so it just looks like the result page is its parent page. :/

Answer (score 0):

According to [the comments in this question's answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/101008/53306), apparently if you don't put an `itemid` onyour last item (current page), it will now be displayed. :)

[Similarly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/95231/53306), you could remove the first item's (home page's) itemid or url to prevent a redundant display like "www.example.com > Home > My page".