# Schema BreadcrumbList wont pull in the last record

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I recently setup Schema.org `BreadcrumbList` on my site. [Check the validation here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=https://lawnmasters.com/tx/houston/landscaping/).

However, the 4th position item URL is not showing. I triple checked and the JSON-LD is validated. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of Google SDTT output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it’s because the URL of the 4th item is the URL of the page you are checking.

If you copy-paste your source code (or simply change a random character somewhere) and check it again, Google’s tool will output the URL for the 4th item.

Nothing you have to change. Providing an item for the current page is [fine according to Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691751/1591669) and also [fine according to Google’s breadcrumbs guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36120336/1591669):

> The breadcrumb trail may include or omit a breadcrumb for the page on which it appears.