# Google not showing full breadcrumbs on SERP as coded with JSON-LD schema markup

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented breadcrumb schema markup with JSON-LD on my website. I have up to 5 positions (levels) of breadcrumbs and my code has validated correctly with the Structured Data Testing Tool.

However I note that Google is not showing the full breadcrumbs on the search results pages. For example for a page with 3 positions (as example code below), Google shows only 2 such as:

> `https://www.example.com` > Jumpers > Mens

Is there anything wrong with my code?

This code would be located on `https://www.example.com/jumpers/mens/designer`:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
  "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 1,
  "name": "Jumpers",
  "item": "https://www.example.com/jumpers"
  }
  ,{
  "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "name": "Mens",
  "item": "https://www.example.com/jumpers/mens"
  }
  ,{
  "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 3,
  "name": "Designer",
  "item": "https://www.example.com/jumpers/mens/designer"
  }]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display of last Schema.org breadcrumb entry in Google Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120148/display-of-last-schema-org-breadcrumb-entry-in-google-search)